# Ruby: How to compare elements one by one within an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Here is first question on stackoverflow :)

consider a random array composed of any integers

```
a = [5, 10, 2, 3, 56]
```

I would like to write a code that will compare each element likewise: element of index i (el_i) with element of index i + 1 (el_i+1) (and continue comparison with element index i + 1 (el_i+1) with element of index  i + 2  (el_i+2) till a.length). Then I would like to sum elements according to the result of the comparison. Here is an example of a failed attempt to picture it:

```
def conditional_sum(array)
  sum = 0
  array.each_with_index do |element, i|
    if array[i] >= array[i + 1]
      sum += element
    else
      sum -= element
    end
  end
  sum
end
```

Another consisted in making 2 arrays from the previous one and delete the last element (I spare you the code to obtain them) an compare elements that have the same index likewise:

```
a = [5, 10, 2, 3, 56]
a_bis = [5, 10, 2, 3]
b = [10, 2, 3, 56]  

sum = 0
for i in [0..a_bis.length]
  if a_bis[i] >= b[i] 
    sum += a_bis[i] + b[i]
  else
    sum -= a_bis[i] + b[i]
  end
end
p sum
```

doesn't work either... Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post the expected output of the method ?

Comment: just the sum of the elements together (integer)

Comment: So how much is that for your example ?

Comment: "doesn't work either" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Also, please provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases. Please provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases. A single example is not a specification, and a single example is also not enough to test all boundary cases.

Comment: According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61631686/ruby-how-to-compare-elements-one-by-one-within-an-array#comment109019821_61631869), the result for the example in your question should be `-62`, but you marked [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61632147/2988) as correct that gives `0` as a result. You can't have it both ways. Either `0` is correct or `-62` is correct, they can't be both correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first example was almost working. Trying it raise the error:

```
`>=': comparison of Integer with nil failed (ArgumentError)
```

It come from the fact that for the last iteration of the index, you compare the last value `56` with `nil`. Ie `56 >= nil` has no sense for ruby, therefore the error. To fix it, you can iterate without the last element. As always in ruby, their are multiple ways to do it. Here is mine :

```rb
def conditional_sum(array)
  sum = 0
  # array[0...-1] will iterate without le last element
  array[0...-1].each_with_index do |element, i|
    if array[i] >= array[i + 1]
      sum += element
    else
      sum -= element
    end
  end
  sum
end
```

Another solution to do what you want would be the following (more functional style). Using the [#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) to select each pair

```rb
def conditional_sum(array)
  array.each_cons(2)
    .sum {|i,j| i >= j ? i : -i}
end
```

Comment: Wait ! careful, you miss the last value here : Need a small fix by adding it again otherwise it returns a wrong result. I had to add array[-1] to the returned value

Comment: What is the rule for the last value ? You can always add to the sum array[-1] or append a `0` value to your input array

Comment: exactly so a small fix needs to happen to take into account the last element. Many thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question:

```
a = [5, 10, 2, 3, 56]

a.each_cons(2).sum do |first, second|
  first > second ? first - second : first + second
end
#=>87
```

[`#each_cons`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_cons) will group them into pairs of consecutive elements:

```
a.each_cons(2) do |pair|
  p pair
end
#=>[5, 10]
#  [10, 2]
#  [2, 3]
#  [3, 56]
```

Then you can execute the desired calculation for each pair inside the block.

Comment: You can use `sum` instead of `map`.

Comment: great start but not fully answered : If I take my array a, I would like the code to do the following : 5 - 10 +2 - 3 - 56 = -62

Comment: @FrançoisCapel You say you want -62, but the accepted answer produces 0. Why are you subtracting 56 at the end ?

Comment: my mistake I got confused at one point. I inserted the code from Raphael Pr above and added the last element that is missing as not taken into account in #each_cons(2) bloc and it works now.

Comment: It's still unclear what the desired result is and what should happen to the last element